# Filtering/excluding list of values in a dict (Python 3)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

With the following dict:

```
dict_filter_test = {'name_one_key': {'name_one_value': ['random_one',
                                 'random_two',
                                 'random_three',
                                 'random_four',
                                 'random_five',
                                 'random_six']},
'name_two_key': {'name_two_value': ['random_one',
                                 'random_two',
                                 'random_three',
                                 'random_four',
                                 'random_five',
                                 'random_six']}}
```

I am trying to exclude strings that contain the following:

```
filter = set(['six', 'two'])
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def filtered_dict():
    for key, value in dict_filter_test.items():

        for value, name in value.items():
            list = [string for string in name
                    if not any(word in string for word in filter)]
            print (list)

    return dict_filter_test
```

The following is an the output that I am trying to get:

```
    {'name_one_key': {'name_one_value': ['random_one',
                                         'random_three',
                                         'random_four',
                                         'random_five']},
     'name_two_key': {'name_two_value': ['random_one',
                                         'random_three',
                                         'random_four',
                                         'random_five']}}
```

Comment: So is this not working or you're not happy with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to reassign the result of the filtered list, reusing the same reference, or the changes are lost.

For this, loop on the values of values (no need for the keys). For each list, rebuild a new filtered list using list comprehension, and assign back the result using *slice notation* (to keep the same reference)

```
filt = ['six', 'two']  # you don't need a set here
for v in dict_filter_test.values():
    for v2 in v.values():
        v2[:] = [x for x in v2 if all(f not in x for f in filt)]
```

result:

```
{'name_two_key': {'name_two_value': ['random_one', 'random_three', 'random_four', 'random_five']},
'name_one_key': {'name_one_value': ['random_one', 'random_three', 'random_four', 'random_five']
}}
```

alternative if you want to fully rebuild the dictionary using a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
dict_filter_test = { k:{k2:[x for x in v2 if all(f not in x for f in filt)] for k2,v2 in v.items()} for k,v in dict_filter_test.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve.